# How to scale map appropriately?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, cartography, scale

I am suppose to make a map.

The specifications are 1:50k scale centered on a certain point. They want to view a distance of 30 miles from that centered point, but when I scale to 1:50k the map is only about an 8 mile range.

How do I do this in ArcGIS 10?

Comment: Hi Will, welcome to GIS.se :) To fetch good answers you'll generally need to add more detail in your questions. The more effort you put in, the more effort others will put in to help. To your question: if what is visible is too small then either a) the paper size needs to be enlarged, or b) a different scale needs to be used.

Comment: Do you have a plotter? What paper format can you print on?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a 1:50K map displaying an area 30 miles wide then your map will need to be 0.0006 miles wide, or about three feet, or over 3600 pixels at 96 DPI (typical computer monitor).

You need to explain to your client that you can show either a desired area or a desired scale but you can't do both at the same time because you generally cannot control the width of the viewport to the extent that you would need to.

Comment: And that's 30 miles from the centered point, so actually 60 miles wide and would require a map just over 76 inches wide! 60 miles * 5280 feet/mile * 12 inches/foot / 50000/1) = 76.032 inches